# Does ef6 ignore null values in columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Has the rule booked changed in EF6 just when I didnt have a value I was referencing in the line address.

```
player _player = new player();
_player =_dal.GetPlayerBYID(new Guid("FBC6D7C8-3460-49A0-B78C-03A8FFE24AFC"));          

txtFirstName.Text = _player.fname.ToString();
txtLastName.Text = _player.lname.ToString();
txtAddress.Text = _player.address.ToString();
```

- it crashed here and said object was not set in ef5 if  a no value was in a column it would still be inlcude

Comment: you should check against null if theres a chance it could be null.

Answer (score 0):

This call to _dal.GetPlayerBYID(new Guid("FBC6D7C8-3460-49A0-B78C-03A8FFE24AFC"));
 may return null.

When the return value is null and you assign it to _player variable, you now have _player = null;

Then when you call fname or lname or address on _player which is null. It will throw an exception. Before calling _player.fname, check it is not null.

i.e

```
if(_player != null)
{

     txtFirstName.Text = _player.fname.ToString();

}
```

Comment: the return value of _player was not ull just the column item of address which cause it to crashed